# Root of a function involving the pdf and cdf of a normal variable

Tags: probability-theory, proof-writing, roots

I am having a hard time proving that the following function:

$f(z)=(z\Phi+\phi)(2\Phi^2-2\Phi+1)-z\Phi^2$ where $\Phi=\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of a standard normal variable, $\phi=\phi(z)$ the pdf of a standard normal variable and $z \in R$.

has no real roots. I have tried several approaches, trying to prove it by contradiction but I have not been succesful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do we know anything about the value spaces of $\phi, \bf \Phi$? Is it a subset of $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$?

Comment: I forgot to say that $\Phi$ is the cdf of a standard normal variable and $\phi$ the pdf, I will edit it.

Comment: Are they of the same variable or of different ones?

Comment: The same one, $\Phi(z)$ and $\phi(z)$

Comment: For  $z>1$,  asymptotic analysis shows that
$$f(z) >\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}-\frac{z}{2} \, \text{erfc}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\right) > 0 \quad \forall z$$